# how do I merge two list[dict] and order properly by its ID?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to merge two `list[dict]` into the following format and order both techniques, and subtechnique, but I am not sure how to properly join them without getting affected other techniques

```
techniques = [{
   "technique_id":"T1548",
   "technique":"demo",
   "url":"url",
   "tactic":[
      "demo",
      "demo"
   ]
}]


subtechniques = [{
   "technique_id":"T1548.002",
   "technique":"demo",
   "url":"url"
}]


def merge_techniques(techniques, subtechniques):
    change_list = []
    for x in techniques:
        for y in subtechniques:
            if x['technique_id'] == y['technique_id'].split('.')[0]:
                print(x)
                print(y)
    return change_list


merge_techniques(techniques, subtechniques)
```

## desired output

```
{
   "technique_id":"T1548",
   "technique":"dmep",
   "url":"https://xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "tactic":[
      "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
   ],
   "subtechnique": [
       {
        "technique_id":"T1548.002",
        "technique":"demo",
        "url":"url"
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your desired output seems to have quite a few errors or at least inconsistencies with the input.

Comment: I update the dict for better understanding @PaulH

Comment: where does `dmep` come from?  at the base, this seems like an easily-answered question, if you could present a clear output requirement.  what you have is not clear at all.  take out 90% of what you have and just leave it as 2 lists with minimal dicts in them.  what do you want as output?  the facts that your dicts are currently complicated adds nothing to your question, it only confuses us and it makes you work overtime to correct inconsistencies in your samples.

Comment: @JLPeyret `dmep` is just sample data . so dont worry about data. I just need to follow the output format via lookup if parent has child subtechniques

Comment: well, i'm not downvoting you, because you're new.  but please understand that this is not conducive to getting answers or upvotes.  what I suggest you do is write the simplest possible 2 dicts in each list **in a script**.  run the script and remove complexity from the data structures till you can't get any simpler without losing the intent of what you want.  then post the script, the current bad result and the desired output.  *dont worry about data* isn't the answer.

Comment: Your example output should match your example input, otherwise the people *volunteering* their time to help you with your problem (that you could be getting compensated for) won't know if their solution is wrong or right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new object, you can discard copy operations.

```py
import copy

def merge_techniques(techniques, subtechniques):
    result = []
    # create technique_id dictionary
    techniques_dict = dict()
    for tech in techniques:
        # create new object
        tech_copy = copy.copy(tech)
        
        techniques_dict[tech['technique_id']] = tech_copy
        result.append(tech_copy)
    
    # visit all sub techniques
    for subtech in subtechniques:
        tech_id = subtech['technique_id'].split('.')[0]
        
        # search by tech_id 
        if tech_id not in techniques_dict:
            # if not found
            print('Tech %s is not found'%(tech_id))
            continue
        
        # get tech by tech_id
        tech = techniques_dict[tech_id]
        
        # create subtechnique array if not existed
        if 'subtechnique' not in tech:
            tech['subtechnique'] = []
            
        # copy subtech object
        tech['subtechnique'].append(copy.copy(subtech))
    
    return result
```